# How to dynamically unpack a list of lists and associate variables to them in python?

Tags: python, list

So here's my dilemma: I am trying to create a program that asks for a number of inputs, and each input needs to be a list that can hold multiple fields. So far the only way I've been able to dynamically create this is through the following:

```
numlists = eval(input("Enter the number of inputs: "))
parent_list = [ [] for i in range(numlists)]
```

The output, if I put in 3, for instance, is [ [], [], [] ]. However, I want to now dynamically unpack parent_list and associate each list instance to a different variable. So if there are 3 inputs, parent_ list gets dynamically unpacked into three separate list variables: child1, child2, and child3. If there are 5, it dynamically unpacks into child1 through child5.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: It might be a little hacky, aren't you ok with storing them in dictionaries instead of variables?

Comment: any time you want to dynamically create variables, you're just asking for a bad time... How do you know if child3 even exists?  It might on some runs of the program and not others -- coding around that problem leads to really hard to read/maintain code.  Juts keep the list of lists and be happy that python lets you do so many cool things with a list :)

Comment: FWIW, http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html is maybe the standard python reference saying that you probably _shouldn't_ do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can do expansion as

```
number_of_lists = 3
list_of_lists = [ [] for i in range(number_of_lists)]
```

however if you want 'named' fields you either want a dictionary or a class, which is hard to tell from your application. Dictionaries are easy:

```
dict_of_lists  = dict ( ("child_%i" % k, []) for k  in range(number_of_lists))
# {'child_0': [], 'child_1': [], 'child_2': []}
```

a class is harder but not too bad:

```
class ListOfLists(object):
   def __init__(self, number_of_lists):
       for n in range (number_of_lists):
           self.__dict__['child_%i' % n] = []
```

However you may want to rephrase your question so it's clearer what you need to do with this data.

Comment: Try `list_of_lists[0].append(1)` and see what happens :)

Comment: downvoted because `list_of_lists = [[]] * number_of_lists` is worse than OP's original code (See comment by Paulo Bu and do the experiment ;).  the named fields bit is good however, so if you fix the first statement, my downvote might transform into an upvote ;-)